# How to install pocketsphinx for python3 on a raspberry pi

Tags: python-3.x, installation, terminal, raspberry-pi3, pocketsphinx

I'm am trying to build my own voice assistant, but the only problem I have run into so far is installing pocketsphinx. I need to use it on python3, but

```
sudo pip3 install pocketsphinx
```

and

```
pip3 install --upgrade pocketsphinx
```

don't work. I am doing this on a raspberry pi3b+ if that makes any difference. I also tried

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx-python/
cd pocketsphinx-python
python setup.py install
```

But I got this:

```
running install
error: can't create or remove files in install directory

The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

    [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/test-easy-install-1601.write-test'

The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/

Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  If the
installation directory is a system-owned directory, you may need to sign in
as the administrator or "root" account.  If you do not have administrative
access to this machine, you may wish to choose a different installation
directory, preferably one that is listed in your PYTHONPATH environment
variable.

For information on other options, you may wish to consult the
documentation at:

  https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/easy_install.html

Please make the appropriate changes for your system and try again.
```

Please help if you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some commands that worked for installation:

```
sudo apt-get install swig libpulse-dev bison libasound2-dev alsa-utils gcc
sudo pip3 install pocketsphinx
```

I hope it helps anyone with the same problem.